# How can I change the background color of a list column header in Quick Edit or Datasheet view?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, css, quick-edit

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 and I am using CSS to style the column headers. I have the column headers color coded so I'm using CSS to change the background color of the headers and the font color of the text in the headers.

When I open the list in Quick Edit view, I lose the styles I applied to my column headers. Is there a way to change the background color and font color of the column headers in Quick Edit view?

Answer (score 1):

Use developer tool to check the element class/attribute so you could limit custom CSS to elements.

Sample demo to custom header background color.

```
<style type="text/css">
    th[role="columnheader"] {
        background-color: azure !important;            
    }
    a[colaction="sort"]{            
        color: red !important;            
    }
</style>
```

[image]